# Render partial with collection with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

Let's say I have an index.js.erb file that gets called remotely. How would I render a partial with a collection and then have jQuery display it on the page.

I'm thinking something along the lines of this (that actually works):

```
$('#eventlist').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => \"memorylist\", :collection => @memories) %>");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks good to me. Only thing I might change is using single quotes on the inside to make it a little more readable:

```
$('#eventlist').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'memorylist', :collection => @memories) %>");
```

Comment: Thanks. It was actually throwing a compile error with my example but changing it to single quotes solved it